# Task focused command-line cheat sheet for linux

Tags: command-line, documents

There are a lot of "Linux command-line cheat sheets" on the internet. But often they only list the commands, sometimes sort and describe them.

What I am looking for is something I would call a "task based" cheat sheet, where I can "ctrl+f" for *what* I want to do and find the corresponding command. Since beforehand I don't know *how* (i.e. the command) to perform the task.

Could someone provide a link or search terms?

##### Explanation:

When trying to do something on the command-line, I normally use google to find a solution. Depending on the complexity of the task, this takes some (unreasonably high) effort and often combining multiple solutions. Also internet access is mandatory for this to work.

I afterwards write this down in a text file and attach some search terms.

Expecting to find similar files on the internet, I search for: `linux task OR action OR work based cheat sheet`, `linux howto collection common tasks`. Those don't return what I look for.

Comment: have you tried searching with the phrase `"how to"` (in quotes) included? because these *tasks* are something you want to know *how to* do :p

Comment: The Linux Documentation Project (`https://tldp.org`) has How-To (task oriented) documents in several (human) languages.

Comment: @ waltinator
I checked it out. It is a step in the right direction. But for my use case, it is too much of a how to and too little cheat sheet. Also the  applications are no everyday / common tasks.

Thank you both, I will update the question. I once found a good guide for the Network example, which illustrated my idea. Unfortunately, I am unable to find it at the moment.

Comment: @Bravo Good idea, I did not. Unluckily, similar results to my phrases. Top result: This question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-structured pdf with basic tasks on the command line:

- [Linux command line for you and me](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/lym/latest/lym.pdf)

Search term:

- `linux where to find good command line documentation`

---

Further reading:

- [A list of sites](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-bsd-documentations.html) which provide Unix documentation, for cases where man-pages are unsuitable.
- [Parser](https://github-wiki-see.page) for GitHub Wikis. Those are not indexed by search engines and were a rich source of information in research.

Of those, matching the question best (in my opinion):

- [The Linux Documentation project](https://tldp.org)
- [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) (Arch is a Linux distribution)
- [GitHub Wiki by Ninna994](https://github.com/Ninna994/docs/wiki/Linux-commands) provides some *how* tags

Having asked the question in person to a few Linux users, I learned most people write this kind of information in a personal wiki.